# How to ignore URL when searching using ElasticSearch？

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi，I have a set of documents which may contains some texts, but may have URLs inside them:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt metus a convallis imperdiet. Praesent interdum magna ut lorem bibendum vehicula. Maecenas consectetur tortor a ex pulvinar, sit amet sollicitudin nunc maximus. Pellentesque non gravida ligula, imperdiet pharetra odio. Nunc non massa vitae mauris tempor tempus. Nulla ac laoreet tellus. Nulla consequat tortor eu eros euismod bibendum. Curabitur ante ligula, aliquet at lacus at, pretium convallis eros. Fusce id mi condimentum, tempor lorem ut, pharetra libero.

https://document.io/document/ipsum

In eget eleifend neque. Morbi ex leo, tincidunt non enim ut, rutrum suscipit metus. Cras laoreet ex ut massa consequat condimentum. Aenean finibus eu nisl ut rhoncus. Aliquam finibus nisl risus, id facilisis justo rutrum et. Aenean enim libero, commodo id mi ut, mattis sollicitudin tellus. Aliquam molestie ligula sit amet lorem malesuada, aliquet pretium dolor malesuada. Phasellus fringilla libero in sollicitudin tristique. Quisque molestie, enim et aliquam dapibus, ex erat ultrices nisi, luctus ornare lorem metus eu sapien.
```

I am using a match query to search words inside the document, however, as you can see sometimes the URL has words that are also part of the actual texts.  This is messing the result up. I am just wondering if ElasticSearch has a way for me to simply ignore the URLs and just focus on the texts?

I am using `english` analyzer for this field at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pattern replace character filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) in your analyzer. For removing URL from your text you can add this filter to your search analyzer:

**Filter:**

```
"char_filter": {
    "type": "pattern_replace",
    "pattern": "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]",
          "replacement": ""
}
```

This filter will replace URL with `empty string` so you will not get result from URL match.